# java.net maven repo - JMS artifact missing

Tags: maven-2, jar, repository, jms

I just created a new Maven project using the default archetype and added the following dependency to my POM file.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Realizing that the Sun's JARs are not on Maven central due to licensing issues, I added 
the following Maven repo to my POM (I know this is bad practice though and that it needs to be added to a settings.xml)

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>Repo ID</id>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <name>Java.net Maven repo</name> 
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

I still see this error in my POM file.

**"Missing artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile"**

Does anyone here know what else needs to be done in addition to the config I already have?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Realizing that the Sun's JARs are not on Maven central due to licensing issues, I added 
>   the following Maven repo to my POM

Yeah, but http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/ doesn't have the jms artifact...

The good news is that the JBoss Nexus repository does have it:

```
<repository>
  <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
  <name>JBoss repository</name>
  <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Do you know if any has source and javadoc jars/poms for JMS?  Apparently JBoss only has the binary JAR.

Comment: If you get the message "No connector available to access repository java.net" after adding the repo the problem is that you are using Maven3, which is not compatible with Maven2 repos. You can either downgrade or add exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894794/maven-failing-to-resolve-recursive-dependencies-with-multiple-repositories

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the jms artifact and don't want to add the whole repo, you can do the following:

```
wget https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar
mvn -e install:install-file -Dfile=./jms-1.1.jar -DartifactId=jms -DgroupId=javax.jms -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually this solution solved the problem for me. I was trying to build Spring RCP 1.1.0 and it failed with the above error. Your solution nailed it. Thanks +1

Comment: You'd better install a custom Maven repository, if you are in a bigger organization, so that your build is reproducible also outside of your local machine.

Answer (score 6):

In fact the real solution for this issue is to use the jms-api-1.1-rev-1.jar artifact available on Maven Central : http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.jms%7Cjms-api%7C1.1-rev-1%7Cjar

Comment: There's and artifact even for JMS-API 2.0: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.jms%7Cjavax.jms-api%7C2.0.1%7Cjar