# Maven failing to resolve recursive dependencies with multiple repositories

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, repository

I'm new to maven so there must be something I don't understand.  But, I've added multiple repositories to resolve multiple dependencies in my POM file.  For some reason its failing while pulling a recursive dependency.  I'm dependent on spring and spring depends upon jms, and it can't find jms.  I'm not sure who tells maven where to find jms is it me or is it inside the POM for spring?  Anyway I've tried adding another repository that contains jms, but it still says it can't find it.  Here is my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype</name>
            <url>http://repository.sonatype.org</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots/>
            <id>repo.pentaho.org</id>
            <name>repo.pentaho.org-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/pentaho</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>thirdparty.pentaho.org</id>
            <name>repo.pentaho.org-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/thirdparty</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.43</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>olap4j-xmla</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
            <artifactId>mondrian</artifactId>
            <version>3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The failure message I get is horrible to read, but here it is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project archiver:
    Could not resolve dependencies for
    project com.fuseanalytics:archiver:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
    The following artifacts could not be resolved:
    javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1,
    com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1,
    com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1:
    Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1
    from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository):
    No connector available to access repository
    java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository)
    of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
    -> [Help 1]
```

Why is it failing to pull this dependency?  Is it the HTTPS?  When I navigate to the URL (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) it is not there anymore.  What do I do in this case?

**Updated:**  Originally I had asked about a slightly different problem, but figured that how because I had an erroneous space in the hostname of my dependencies.  Once I removed that I encountered a new error message.

Comment: appears like you've been hit by the reference to outdated repo URL. Try adding to repositories something like `<repository> <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id> <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name> <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url> <layout>default</layout> </repository>` see http://maven2-repository.java.net/

Comment: I tried that, but since I'm not declaring the dependency, a dependency I depend upon is declaring it as a dependency so adding that repo  doesn't seem to help.  I would expect my POM could override it a dependency, but it doesn't work.

Comment: sounds painfully familiar. Try this: 1) use `mvn dependency:tree` to find "offenders", eg those declaring dep on `javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1`, 2) exclude the offending dependencies 3) repeat until you will need to declare all problematic deps yourself -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547805/how-to-exclude-all-transitive-dependencies-of-a-maven-dependency

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are running Maven 3+ and you are trying to access a legacy repository.

One annoying but well documented change for Maven 3 was removing support for legacy repositories. You can check out this compatibility note and others [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes)

If you are not depending completely on Maven 3 you can reduce to Maven 2.2.1 and this legacy issue should go away or follow what the link says and create a

> Maven 2.x compatible view of the legacy repository

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I ended up not downgrading, and using exclusions on the dependencies to turn off transitive dependencies like jms, etc.  I don't know what that exactly does for packaging because I probably need those things to run.  Seems like a serious problem with Maven3 adoption if we can't get sun jar files because they are on an old repository maven 1 layout.  I didn't like maven before I started this, and this experience hasn't changed my opinion much.  I like dependency management, but its been such a headache.

Answer (score 24):

Just got this problem: log4j version 1.2.15 is causing this problem. 
Using log4j version 1.12.16 removes this problem. 
see [Missing artifact com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047949/missing-artifact-com-sun-jdmkjmxtoolsjar1-2-1)

Comment: this strange error message got solve by using log4j 1.2.17 , thanks

Answer (score 11):

I may be a little late to the party, but someone using log4j 1.2.15 may search for it in the future. The problem is resolved with this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

*I found two solution for the problem , both are equally effective .*

1. Download jar and install locally

   `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`

---

2 .  Exclusion of dependencies

```
`<dependency> .... <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId> ... <artifactId>...</exclusion>`
```

[maven  dependency exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think [download jmx1.2.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html#7657-jmx-1.2.1-oth-JPR) will help you :-), try upload it to your nexus

Answer (score -1):

```
You should use 2 repository like bellow:
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
            <name>JBoss repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```