# Maven error while setting up i.lon 100 server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to connect i.lon100 with JAVA using Programmers Reference. pom.xml and .pdf file with Programmer reference can be downloaded from page: http://home.elka.pw.edu.pl/~mkolasin/

My eclipse version is:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2

Build id: 20130225-0426

Maven version: 2.2.1 (as recomended in programmers reference)

a) First of all I have a problem with page 22-6 with installing Maven Embedder and Maven Integration for Eclipse, becouse I assume that http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/ page doesn't exsist. So, my first question: is there any other site I can download those software using eclipse?

B) I installed from eclipse market: Maven integration for eclipse, but i couldn't find Maven Embedder. And now i have got right click on project: RUN AS - Maven Built instead of Run AS - maven package is it still okay?

c) When i try to make another step page 22-13 "In the Project Explorer view, right-click the ilon-ws folder, point to Run As, and then click
Maven Package. This generates the java proxy classes and builds the jar." i got an error in console and i don't know how to fix it.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org...ticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.echelon.es:ilon-ws:jar:4.03-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 71, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 113, column 23
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing. @ line 124, column 23
[WARNING] 'repositories.repository.layout' for java.net uses the unsupported value 'legacy', artifact resolution might fail. @ line 36, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ECHELON i.LON SmartServer 4.03-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.985s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 04 20:20:25 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ilon-ws: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.echelon.es:ilon-ws:jar:4.03-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.1: Could not transfer artifact woodstox:wstx-asl:pom:3.2.1 from/to java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1/): No connector available to access repository java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1/) of type legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache....lutionException
```

I tried adding slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar file to buildpath and nothing has changed.

Please give me any suggestions or help, becouse I can't handle it since last few days, and i don't know where to find answers.

Regards,
Kolata

Comment: Could help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7895900/319878. Seems you might be using Maven 3 to access a legacy (Maven 1) repository.

Comment: Not sure why your build is trying to use the java.net repo when the dependencies you need seem to be in Maven Central. E.g. http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.sun.xml.ws|jaxws-rt|2.2|jar and http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|woodstox|wstx-asl|3.2.1|N%2FA.

Comment: I use Maven 3 which is build in eclipse, I'll try with older eclipse (3.6 helios) with maven 2.2.1

Comment: Maybe ignore Eclipse and try a build from the command line first, using Maven 2.2.1.

Comment: Is Run As Maven Package the same as Run As Maven Build?