# Why eclipse complaining about the missing dependency I added?

Tags: java, scala, maven, pom.xml

Eclipse says it needs com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1, then I added in the pom as below. But then it complains about the dependency I just added, why is that?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your Maven dependencies?

Comment: I did the Maven -> Update Project , but doesn't help, still same error

Comment: What about `mvn depenendency:resolve`?

Comment: mvn dependency:resolve gives me the error: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'depenendency' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/edamame/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: So that implies that you have a syntax error with your POM.  Post the actual code of your POM (at least enough to replicate the issue; 200+ lines is a bit much) here in text, and not a picture, so that one could poke and prod at it in an IDE.

Comment: Here are a few lines that have the errors ... I can post more, but not sure how do I post more in the comment:    <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.scopt</groupId>
   <artifactId>scopt_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
   <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
   <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing artifact com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047949/missing-artifact-com-sun-jdmkjmxtoolsjar1-2-1)

Comment: BTW, if I remove those dependencies, this is the errors I got on the top of the pom:Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1 from https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will 
  not be reattempted until the update interval of java.net has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-
  repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository):

Comment: continue above: No connector available to access repository java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) of type legacy using the available 
  factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory,

Comment: What I meant was that you edit this information into the question.  It's too hard to read the comments for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer: [Maven failing to resolve recursive dependencies with multiple repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894794/maven-failing-to-resolve-recursive-dependencies-with-multiple-repositories)

need to change log4j from 1.2.15 to 1.2.16

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The above dependencies where accidentally in the log4j pom. The new version fixed the problem.