# How to repair my POM with missing artifact?

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem with a POM which is not mine. Here is it.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sms.smsoffice</groupId>
        <artifactId>sms-office</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sms-office-ui</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>sms office ui</name>
    <description>sms office ui</description>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/resources</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make shared resources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/resources.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Project Internal Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>sms-office-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- External dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-auth-roles</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.auth-roles.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the error: Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B

Failure to transfer javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of java.net has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector factories: AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory

Please help

Comment: Might want to try this answer on [maven-failing-to-resolve-recursive-dependencies-with-multiple-repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894794/maven-failing-to-resolve-recursive-dependencies-with-multiple-repositories#answer-25075085). Looks like excluding a few dependencies from log4j does the trick.

Comment: its not log4j I tried...

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19086931/4311135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want really want that javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B artifact, it's available [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar), so you can either add http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2/ as a [repository in your pom](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) to have maven download it, or download it manually and [install it yourself](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

But what you should probably do instead is upgrade your log4j version to be 1.2.17 because 1.2.15 [has bad metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048062/2646526).  You'll also likely want to depend on org.apache.wicket:wicket-core instead of org.apache.wicket:wicket because org.apache.wicket:wicket is an [aggregator project](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation), not a jar.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this dependency to the POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1B</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: when I add this, on the dependency shows this error: Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B

Comment: What does `on the dependency shows this error` mean?  Did you do a `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: yes I did clean install and next to the your new dependency I pasted there it shows this error: Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B. And also its underline with red. In fact this could not be found

Comment: OK it's time to get heavy-handed here.  Can you delete the _entire_ `javax` directory from your `.m2` folder?  Then do a `mvn clean install` and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple exculde the jta artifact from the problematic dependency.
For example:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
            <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```