# soapui maven plugin jms not found

Tags: maven, soapui

I ran into an error trying to test a WS using soapui maven plugin :

```
15:06:45,391 ERROR [AbstractTestRunner] Exception during Test Execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry.<clinit>(RequestTransportRegistry.java:47)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest.submit(WsdlRequest.java:240)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep.run(WsdlTestRequestStep.java:419)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:52)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:152)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:47)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 13 more
```

My pom is like the exemple on soapui website.

I'm trying to just run a simple test on my WS :

```
<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <soapui.version>5.0.0</soapui.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${soapui.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>test-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I tryed to add dependencies to jms in the the plugin and/or out the plugin.
Where this come from ?
Anyone got this error too ?
What am I missing ?

Comment: `configuration` is suppose to be a child of `plugin`.

Comment: In here it isn't http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html at lest in full exemple, I still get the error with configuration in plugin.

Comment: I think the "full example" on that page is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but it seem like it's not the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proble is that JMS jar isn't present on maven central repo : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/jms/1.1 try to download it you will get a 404.

Thanks to this answer : [java.net maven repo - JMS artifact missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622773/java-net-maven-repo-jms-artifact-missing)

I found it here : https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/jms/jms/1.1/ thanks JBoss.