# Using ojdbc with SoapUI's maven plugin

Tags: oracle, maven, jdbc, groovy, soapui

I have faced a problem and I have no idea what's going on, so I decided to ask for help.
I'm using SoapUI's plugin for Maven, got this in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
<artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.6.1</version>
...
</plugin>
```

I also have the ojdbc dependency in pom.xml, like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have a test step in groovy, like this:

```
import java.sql.*;
def path="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
def username='xxxxx'
def password='xxxxx'
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(path, username, password)    /// Error here.
```

I have included the same ojdbc6.jar in my SoapUI's project. The same files - in Maven project and in SoapUI.
My question is:
Why am I getting `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxxx` using Maven? When I run it in SoapUI everything is working properly, no errors, no exceptions... Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [soapui maven plugin jms not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904150/soapui-maven-plugin-jms-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the JDBC dependency **in** the plugin, not the project:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>...</projectFile>
                ...
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I still see the same error though I have added the dependency?

Comment: @user2062360 From Groovy, you also need to register the driver: https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#10-Use-a-JDBC-Driver-from-inside-a-groovy-script